# How can I use a dispatcher middleware on flask?

Tags: python, flask, middleware, wsgi

I am trying to use the `wsgi DispatcherMiddleware` in order to prefix a url on my application. I've written one module for the dispatcher and one for the app, which has just one view called *home* and this is where the homepage is served from.

here is my **app1.py**

```
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


@app.route('/home', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return "<h1>Home</h1>"
```

and **dispatcher.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.exceptions import NotFound

from app1 import app


app = Flask(__name__)

app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(NotFound(), {
    "/prefix": app
})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

what I wanna do is be able to navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/prefix/home`
when I run on console `py dispatcher.py`, but however when I navigate on that url I get a `404` response. What works in only the navigation to the page`http://127.0.0.1:5000/home`. Could someone help me understand why this happens? I appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: Did you try using a Blueprint for prefixing routes? See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/tutorial/views/#create-a-blueprint and `url_prefix` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I was using wrong tha same name for the `dispacher` and the `app1`.

**dispacher.py** should be edited as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.exceptions import NotFound

from app1 import app as app1


app = Flask(__name__)

app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(NotFound(), {
    "/prefix": app1
})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding prefix to all routes is really simple if you opt for using Blueprints

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/tutorial/views/#create-a-blueprint

```py
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
prefixed = Blueprint('prefixed', __name__, url_prefix='/prefixed')

@app.route('/nonprefixed')
def non_prefixed_route():
    return 'this is the nonprefixed route'

@prefixed.route('/route')
def some_route():
    return 'this is the prefixed route'


app.register_blueprint(prefixed)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Testing the routes:

```
> curl localhost:5000/
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>

> curl localhost:5000/nonprefixed
this is the nonprefixed route

> curl localhost:5000/prefixed/route
this is the prefixed route
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I wanna use an application dispacher though because I wanna allow many applications to be interconnected